# IBM Http server and Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, webserver, ibmhttpserver

HI I am configuring IBM HTTP Server as a front end of a tomcat application listening to port 9001. The webserver and the appserver (tomcat) are on different machines. Machine A as IHS Installed. my question is where do I tell to machine A (IHS) to send the requests to Machine B (Tomcat on 9001 port). In httpd.conf what exactly to add so that all requests hitting the webserver should reach machine B the tomcat server. both are linux machines.

Comment: Its done by the worker file :)

Answer (score 0):

IHS 8.0 and 8.5 are both built on core Apache version 2.2.8.
IHS 9.0 is Apacje 2.4 so configs might be a bit different.

Look into Apache docs how to enable mod_proxy and write preverse proxy stanza like

ProxyPass "/foo" "http://foo.example.com/bar"
ProxyPassReverse "/foo" "http://foo.example.com/bar"

Docs: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Alternatively hack plugins-config.xml although this might be overwritten by Websphere... see...

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/was_install/t_config_web_plugin_ihs8.htm#t_config_web_plugin_ihs8

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I could solve it thru a worker file